# How can I add a user's email address into the footer of a Google Doc using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Apps Script in a Google Doc to capture a user's email address and put that email address in the footer of the Doc but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, how about focusing on one aspect of the problem, say, merging a value into a Google doc, and post up what you've got so far.

Comment: Take a look at [this section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footer-section#appendParagraph(String)) of the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Adding text to footer in Google Docs:

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter().appendParagraph('youremail');
```